# Why this simple program in C crashes (array VS pointer)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, extern

I have two files:

In file **1.c** I have the following array:

```
char p[] = "abcdefg";
```

In file **0.c** I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char *p; /* declared as 'char p[] = "abcdefg";' in 1.c file */

int main()
{
    printf("%c\n", p[3]);   /* crash */
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the command line:

```
gcc  -Wall -Wextra     0.c  1.c
```

I know that `extern char *p` should've been: `extern char p[];`, but I just want an explanation of **why it doesn't work in this particular case**. While it works here:

```
int main()
{
    char a[] = "abcdefg";
    char *p = a;

    printf("%c\n", p[3]);   /* d */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you have declared a variable with two conflicting types and asking why it is not working?

Comment: Loo k at the assembler files (`gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O`)

Comment: in `1.c` `p` is an *array*, in `0.c` it is a *pointer*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. but it works in the second example

Comment: In the second example it is something completely different. In first one you have fooled the linker who doesn't know the type of `p` and it paid it back to you. In the second one everyone knows everything.

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Compile with `gcc -flto -O -g -Wall -Wextra 0.c 1.c -o badprog` and you'll get at least a warning

Comment: @BiteBytes the second example makes no attempts to *lie* and treat a *single* `id` with two different types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your two examples are not comparable.

In your second example, you have

```
char a[] = "abcdefg";
char *p = a;
```

So `a` is an array, and `p` is a pointer.  Drawing that in pictures, it looks like

```
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   a: | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | \0|
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
        ^
        |
   +----|----+
p: |    *    |
   +---------+
```

And this is all fine; no problems with that code.

But in your first example, in file `1.c` you define an array named `p`:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
p: | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | \0|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You can name an array "`p`" if you want (the compiler certainly doesn't care), but then, over in file `0.c`, you change your mind and declare that `p` is a pointer.  You also declare (with the "`extern`" keyword) that `p` is defined somewhere else.  So the compiler takes your word for it, and emits code that goes to location `p` and expects to find a pointer there -- or, in pictures, it expects to find a box, containing an arrow, that points somewhere else.  But what it actually finds there is your string `"abcdefg"`, only it doesn't realize it.  It will probably end up trying to interpret the bytes `0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64` (that is, the bytes making up the first part of the string `"abcdefg"`) as a pointer.  Obviously that doesn't work.

You can see this clearly if you change the `printf` call in `0.c` to

```
printf("%p\n", p);
```

This prints the value of the pointer `p` *as a pointer*.  (Well, of course, `p` isn't really a pointer, but you lied to the compiler and told it that it was, so what you'll see is the result when the compiler treats it as a pointer, which is what we're trying to understand here.)  On my system this prints

```
0x67666564636261
```

That's all 8 bytes of the string `"abcdefg\0"`, in reverse order.  (From this we can infer that I'm on a machine which (a) uses 64-bit pointers and (b) is little-endian.)  So if I tried to print

```
printf("%c\n", p[3]);
```

it would try to fetch a character from location `0x67666564636264` (that is, `0x67666564636261` + 3) and print it.  Now, my machine has a fair amount of memory, but it doesn't have *that* much, so location `0x67666564636264` doesn't exist, and therefore the program crashes when it tries to fetch from there.

Two more things.

If arrays are not the same as pointers, how did you get away with saying

```
char *p = a;
```

in your second example, the one I said was "all fine; no problems"?
How can you assign an array on the right-hand side to a pointer on the left?
The answer is the famous (infamous?) "equivalence between arrays and pointers in C": what actually happens is just as if you had said

```
char *p = &a[0];
```

Whenever you use an array in an expression, what you get is actually a pointer to the array's first element, just as I showed in the first picture in this answer.

And when you asked, "why it doesn't work, while it works here?", there were two other ways you could have asked it.
Suppose we have the two functions

```
void print_char_pointer(char *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", p);
}

void print_char_array(char a[])
{
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

And then suppose we go back to your second example, with

```
char a[] = "abcdefg";
char *p = a;
```

and suppose that we call

```
print_char_pointer(a);
```

or

```
print_char_array(p);
```

If you try it, you'll find that there are no problems with either of them.
But how can this be?  How can we pass an array to a
function that expects a pointer, when we call `print_char_pointer(a)`?
And how can we pass a pointer to a
function that expects an array, when we call `print_char_array(p)`?

Well, remember, whenever we mention an array in an expression,
what we get is a pointer to the array's first element.  So when
we call

```
print_char_pointer(a);
```

what we get is just as if we had written

```
print_char_pointer(&a[0]);
```

What actually gets passed to the function is a pointer, which is
what the function expects, so we're fine.

But what about the other case, where we pass a pointer to a function that's declared as if it accepts an array?  Well, there's actually another tenet to the "equivalence between arrays and pointers in C".
When we wrote

```
void print_char_array(char a[])
```

the compile treated it just as if we had written

```
void print_char_array(char *a)
```

Why would the compiler do such a thing?  Why, because it knows
that no array will ever be passed to a function, so it knows that no
function will actually ever receive an array, so it knows that the
function will receive a pointer instead. So that's the way the
compiler treats it.

(And, to be very clear, when we talk about the "equivalence
between arrays and pointers in C", we are not saying that
pointers and arrays *are* equivalent, just that there is this
special equivalence relationship between them.  I've mentioned
two of the tenets of that equivalence already.  Here are all
three of them, for reference: (1) Whenever you
mention the name of an array in an expression, what you
automatically get is a pointer to the array's first element.
(2) Whenever you declare a function that seems to accept an
array, what it actually accepts is a pointer.  (3) Whenever you
use the "array" subscripting operator, `[]`, on a pointer, as in
`p[i]`, what you actually get is just as if you had written `*(p + i)`.  And, in fact, if you think about it carefully, due to
tenet (1), even when you use the array subscripting operator on
something that looks like an array, you're actually using it on a
pointer.  But that's a pretty strange notion, which you don't
have to worry about if you don't want to, because it just works.)

Answer (score 4):

Because arrays are not pointers. You tell the program "elsewhere I have a char pointer", but you actually don't have one - you have an array.

An array will decay into a pointer when used in an expression, but that doesn't mean that an array *is* a pointer. For more info see [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer).

In your second example you have both an array *and* a pointer, two separate variables, so it is a different case.

Answer (score 4):

Let me explain it in reverse:

In the second case, you have an array and then a pointer which points to that array.

Accessing via the pointer involves an indirect memory address ("print the 3rd byte from where this pointer points to" vs. "print the 3rd byte of this array").

In the first case, you have an array somewhere else, but tell the compiler you had a pointer at that place. So it tries to read that pointer and read the data from where it points to. But there is no pointer – there is the data immediately, so the pointer points to "anywhere and nowhere" (at least, quite likely). This constitutes undefined behaviour (often abbreviated as UB).