# char array vs. char pointer in C

Tags: extern

I used to think it is equivalent to declare a char pointer as `char* s` or `char s[]`.  It turns out they are not equivalent.

Suppose I have a file a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern char s[];

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

and another file b.c:

```
char s[10] = "Hello";
```

I can compile and link these two files by "gcc a.c b.c".  Running the program gets the expected result "Hello".

However, if in "a.c" I declare the variable s as `extern char* s`, the program can be compiled without any error or warning, but running the program results in a "Segmentation fault".
I used to think an array name, when it is being used without brackets, is equivalent to a pointer.
Then, what causes the above run-time error?

In a.c, I tried to declare s in two different ways:

1. extern char s[];
2. extern char* s;
   I expect these two ways should be equivalent, but the former succeeds while the latter has run-time error.
   I saw in [Why this simple program in C crashes (array VS pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222953/why-this-simple-program-in-c-crashes-array-vs-pointer) people said `char s[]` and `char* s` are two different types.  My main question is, inside the same program, these types seem to be interchangeable.  Why will it fail with extern variables?